# If statement in my function doesn't get called (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

The if statement in my function doesn't get called even though the requirements are fulfilled. When I added an else at the end it always got executed.

```
async def select_callback(self,interaction,select):
    for i in self.children:
        i.disabled = True
    embed_product = discord.Embed(description="Hello")
    if select.values[0][0:-1] == "M":
        if select.values[0][-1] == "F":
            embed_product = create_embed("Месяц","FULL")
            return embed_product
        elif select.values[0][-1] == "C":
            embed_product = create_embed("Месяц","Classic")
    elif select.values[0][0:-1] == "Г":
        if select.values[0][-1] == "F":
            embed_product = create_embed("Год","FULL")
        elif select.values[0][-1] == "C":
            embed_product = create_embed("Год","Classic")
    elif select.values[0][0:-1] == "гМ":
        if select.values[0][-1] == "F":
            embed_product = create_embed("Гифтом месяц","FULL")
        elif select.values[0][-1] == "C":
            embed_product = create_embed("Гифтом месяц","Classic")
    elif select.values[0][0:-1] == "гГ":
        embed_product = create_embed("Гифтом год","FULL")
    elif select.values[0][0:-1] == "QRМ":
        if select.values[0][-1] == "F":
            embed_product = create_embed("Гифтом месяц","FULL")
        elif select.values[0][-1] == "C":
            embed_product = create_embed("Гифтом месяц","Classic")
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Nothing worked except when I put `if True:`. Even when I put `select.values[0][0:-1] == select.values[0][0:-1]`.

Comment: Can you add a print above the if-statement to see why? Something like `print(select.values[0], select.values[0][:-1], select.values[0][:-1] == "M")`.

Comment: Thank you, it actually showed me that python viewed them as different

Answer (score 0):

It was because I used the same letter but from a different language, so even thought they looked and meant the same, python considered them as different.